# Robotium : Asserting strings with quotes by fetching from excel files using JXL API

Tags: robotium, jxl

I am trying to assert a string which is getting fetched from excel file.I am using JXL Api for  reading excel files.

My problem is:
Click "Save" when done. is the string on my screen.

When I am using the string directly like this:
"Click \"Save\" when done." it is working fine with the code: assertTrue("not equals",solo.searchText("Click \"Save\" when done.");

But while fetching from external excel file its not asserting. I am entering Click \"Save\" when done. in the excel cell.

Answer (score 0):

Use solo.searchText(Pattern.qoute("Click \"Save\" when done."))

Comment: This is not my problem Exactly. I am already using this Pattern.quote and its working fine when I am initializing the string directly but problem is with Fetching it from EXCEL file. I am using JXL API and what should be the text that I should enter in that excel file so that it will pick up the exact string I want.